# Get Meta Data content scripts in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I used chrome.tabs to get the meta data in content scripts for chrome extension. but it dosen't work because the chrome.tabs is only used in background script and popup script.

How do I have to do to get the meta data of active page in content scripts?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of data you require from `tabs` API?

Answer (score 1):

Since, as you noticed, a content script can't call `tabs` API, it need to *ask something that can* to do it.

That *something* is a [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages), or even better, [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).

*Asking* in this case means sending [Messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). A message from a content script will be stamped with the `Tab` object of the page it comes from, so you don't need to look for it.

```
// Content script
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "getTabDetails"}, function(response) {
  // response.id is the tab ID
});

// Event script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.action === "getTabDetails") {
    // Here, sender.tab will be the tab you need; you can pass whatever data
    //   required back. For example, the ID:
    sendResponse({id: sender.tab.id});
  }
});
```